# Extract dataframe column text within brackets

Tags: r, dataframe

For an example dataframe:

```
           Name Value
1 Katie (5676W)  <NA>
2  John (2345G)  <NA>
3   Hex (4563W)  <NA>
4  Mike (4564R)  <NA>

df <- structure(list(
          Name = c("Katie (5676W)", "John (2345G)", "Hex (4563W)", 
   "Mike (4564R)"),
          Value = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)),
          .Names = c("Name", "Value"),
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
          row.names = c(NA, -4L),
          spec = structure(list(
            cols = structure(list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
      "collector")), Value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
      "collector"))), .Names = c("Name", "Value")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
      "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

I wish to extract the numbers and letters contained within the bracket and instead add it (minus the brackets to the 'value' column) in the df dataframe.

I have seen how on Stackoverflow to extract it if it was in a vector, but haven't managed to get it working in a dataframe. Any ideas?

Comment: Would this suffice? `do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$Name, ' '))`

Comment: I added what your df looks like. You meant "extract the contents within brackets, from the Name column". Are you guaranteed that column has the exact format *"Firstname (alphanumeric string)"*? always two fields, with no other whitespace or punctuation? Depending on that, you could use a simple split, or a regex, or a harder regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
library(qdapRegex)
df$Value = rm_between(df$Name, '(', ')', extract=TRUE)
```

output:

```
           Name Value
1 Katie (5676W) 5676W
2  John (2345G) 2345G
3   Hex (4563W) 4563W
4  Mike (4564R) 4564R
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: (I use the `stringr`-package, but it can be done in base R, too)

```
library(stringr)
df$Value <- str_extract(df$Name, "\\(.*\\)")
df$Value <- str_remove_all(df$Value, "[\\(\\)]")

df
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#   Name          Value
#   <chr>         <chr>
# 1 Katie (5676W) 5676W
# 2 John (2345G)  2345G
# 3 Hex (4563W)   4563W
# 4 Mike (4564R)  4564R
```

With base R you can do:

```
df$Value <- sub("(.*\\()(.*)(\\))", "\\2", df$Name)
```